# Searching for files using filters in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, toolbar, file-filter

I had Windows 7 recently, how can i search for files (*.pom files) which contain a string, using a filter so the search do not take a long time?
is there a query language to use in the search tool bar?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a tool named FileSearchEX that uses a search engine similar to the Windows XP search tool, it has a a trial period, but you can uninstall/install it many times if you want, it could be integrated to the explorer menu ;)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Run:

Search "search string" in file *.pom (fulltext search engines):

```
search-ms:query=(ext:.pom) "search string"
```

Search file *.pom except "search string" in file name:

```
search-ms:query=((ext:.pom)LIKE(-filename:"*search string*.pom"))
```

Search file *.pom AND "search string" in file name:

```
search-ms:query=((ext:.pom)LIKE(filename:"*search string*.pom"))
```

Comment: Thank you STTR for your reply, may be i was not clear in my first question, but i am seraching pom files which have in their content my string not in the name of the files ;)

Comment: @jamesbaron Updated, see again.

Answer (score 0):

The FileSearchEx trial period was over before I'd had a chance to get used to it, or try it out properly, and the current version does not get re-enabled by uninstalling/reinstalling.

There was nothing on the website to say how long the trial period was for, so I asked before I installed it.  I was told it varies.  Great.

It could well be useful, but it's the sort of utility that may only get used once in a while, so the trial period needs to be long enough to see if it's what you want.  I only used it maybe a couple of times, before I no longer could without paying for it.  I wasn't sure I wanted to.

Instead, I googled again and found XSearch from easexp.com, which is freeware / donation ware - very fast, and does pretty much the same thing.  Try that too, before you decide.

Comment: You might want to move the important part of this answer to the top, so readers don't have to wade through the story before they get to it.